# Get num of page with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to get the number of pages in the next code html:

```
<span id="viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterInfoNumPagMAQ" class="outputText marginLeft0punto5">1</span>

<span id="viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterInfoTotalPaginaMAQ" class="outputText marginLeft0punto5">37</span>

<span id="viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterTotalTotalMAQ" class="outputText marginLeft0punto5">736</span>
```

The goal is get the number 1, 37 and 736

My problem is that i don't know how define the line to extract the numbers, for example for the number 1:

```
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
first_page = int(soup.find('span', {'id': 'viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterInfoNumPagMAQ'}).getText())
```

Thanks so much

EDIT: Finally i found a solution with Selenium:

```
numpag = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterInfoNumPagMAQ"]').text)
pagtotal = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterInfoTotalPaginaMAQ"]').text)
totaltotal = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterTotalTotalMAQ"]').text)
```

Thanks @abarnert, sorry for the caos in my question, it was my first post =)

Comment: Use `soup.find_all` and iterate over the `ResultSet`

Comment: The code you've presented works with the example you've given. (Although you shouldn't be using the undocumented legacy `getText` method that's only there for BS3 compatibility; just use the `text` attribute.) So… what's the problem here?

Comment: Is the problem that it works for this example, but doesn't work the next time you fetch a new page, because those IDs are auto-generated or something? If so, you need to explain that in your question. (The answer is probably going to be using a regex match or function match instead of a string match for `id`, but you'll need to show us a different example that doesn't work with the existing code before I could be sure of exactly what the regex or function should be.)

Comment: Sorry the error in terminal is:

first_page = int(soup.find('span', {'id': 'viewns_Z7_AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004_:form1:textfooterInfoNumPagMAQ'}).getText())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Comment: @Davicholo First, edit that into the question, don't paste it as a comment. Second, you _don't_ get that for the example in your question, so you need to give us an example that actually reproduces your error. Please read [mcve] in the help.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided already works for the example you provided.

My guess is that your problem is that it doesn't work for any other page, probably because those `id` values are different each time.

If that's the case, you need to look at (or show us) multiple different outputs to figure out if there's a recognizable pattern that you can match with a regular expression or a function full of string operations or whatever. See [Searching the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) in the docs for the different kinds of filters you can use.

---

As a wild guess, that `Z7` and `AVEQAI930OBRD02JPMTPG21004` are replaced by different strings of capitals and digits each time, but the rest of the format is always the same? If so, there are some pretty obvious regular expressions you can use:

```
rnumpag = re.compile(r'.*:form1:textfooterInfoNumPagMAQ')
rtotalpagina = re.compile(r'.*:form1:textfooterInfoTotalPaginaMAQ')
rtotaltotal = re.compile(r'.*:form1:textfooterTotalTotalMAQ')

numpag = int(soup.find('span', id=rnumpag).string)
totalpagina = int(soup.find('span', id=rtotalpagina).string)
totaltotal = int(soup.find('span', id=rtotaltotal).string)
```

This works on your provided example, and would also work on a different page that had different strings of characters within the part we're matching with `.*`.

And, even if my wild guess was wrong, this should show you how to write a search for whatever you actually *do* have to search for.

---

As a side note, you were using the undocumented legacy function `getText()`. This implies that you're copying and pasting ancient BS3 code. Don't do that. Some of it will work with BS4, even when it isn't documented to (as in this case), but it's still a bad idea. It's like trying to run Python 2 source code with Python 3 without understanding the differences.

What you want here is either `get_text()`, `string`, or `text`, and you should look at what all three of these mean in the docs to understand the difference—but here, the only thing within the tag is a text string, so they all happen to do the same thing.